# disabling Windows phone map control

Tags: windows-phone

My quesiton is: i have a windows phone 8 app - it has a Map Control on a page that shows the user's position.
We want to allow the user to disable the map control so it looks greyed out and disbaled and doesnt update (to save bandwith etc)

What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply draw a control with semitransparent background on top of the map. thus all touch events would be stuck in the control, but the map would be visible under it still.